# Синтаксическая ошибка в коде

Tags: python

Мой код:

```
 @client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')
    await greatSender()
```

Но почему то выдёт ошибку:

```
  File "main.py", line 98
    async def on_ready():
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Если не учитывать лишний пробел слева от `@client.event` (если бы в нем была проблема, то была бы ошибка IndentationError), то в приведенном коде ошибок нет. Ошибка либо выше (например, незакрытая скобка), либо запускаете старой версией Python, в которой нет async/await.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала:

`pip install asyncio`

И надо заменить

```
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')
    await greatSender()
```

на

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')
    await greatSender()
```

а вместо await

```
yield from coroutine()
```

*async и await были добавлены в python 3.5. Тут зависит от версии.*